# use AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll to grab video thumbnail

Tags: asp.net, ffmpeg

I am using AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll to grab video thumbnail on website, it will be shown on webpage or other clients. I downloaded latest version of the dll and related native library into /bin folder and copied to system32 folder as well.

but when I **compiled** the project, it will told me:
"
**Could not load file or assembly 'AForge.Video.FFMPEG.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.**
"

1. I copied all DLLs
   [image]
2. All DLLs are 32bit, not x64 bit.
3. I saw another article to introduce how to load native c or managed c++ library in asp.net, but doesn't work for me.
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorman/archive/2007/08/31/loading-c-assemblies-in-asp-net.aspx
4. My developing environment: Windows2012R2 VS2010
5. When I was compiling the project, compiler will throw above exception.

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 1):

You must download and copy "postproc-52.dll" too.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net loads native dlls - like the ones used in `AForge.Video.FFMPEG` - using Win32 API `LoadLibrary` which searches for the library in the folder the executable resides in.

When a library is loaded like this in a desktop application the folder the executable resides in is the bin folder but in ASP.Net the main executable *is* ASP.Net not your website/app, hence the folder `LoadLibrary` searches in is `windows\system32` not bin.

You could just copy all the dlls to 'system32` but I wouldn't recommend doing so.. There are alternatives but I don't know much about them so I can't explain them, try searching google.